# Tabbed navigation conect with slider

Tags: navigation, slider, jssor, tabbed

I use Jssor Content slider and I want to connect three navigation buttons (Value My Home, Rent My Home and Property Market Analysis) with appropriate slide from slider, but I don't know how.
It's link from my webpage:
http://casssh.com/ValueMyHome/SaB/index.html

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please listen to `click` event on your tab element, and then call `$PlayTo` method of the slider.

For example,

```
//play to the 3rd slide of the slider
jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(2);
```

Comment: I create click event on the tab element:<br/>

    `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li, .navlink").click(function()
 {
        jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(2);
    });
});
</script>`

but I don't know hot to call $PlayTo method...
...

    `<ul class="navlist">
                  <li class="navlink">Value My Home</li>
                  <li class="navlink">Rent My Home</li>`
...

Comment: Right, if you know which one is clicked, you'd know which slide you'd `$PlayTo`.